# How do I fix my computer via BusyBox?

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, crash, busybox

[3DSlicer](https://www.slicer.org/) froze my computer importing a CT set, and not finding any way to fix it, I held the power button 'til it shut off.

Booting up, after selecting 'Ubuntu' from the boot menu, I am met with a black screen saying:

> lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
>   /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root contains a file system with errors, check
>   forced. Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
>
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck
>   MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options) fsck exited with status
>   code 4 The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires a
>   manual fsck
>
> BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter
>   'help' for a list of built-in commands.
>
> (initramfs)

Typing 'help', 'fsck' is not one of the listed built-in commands. Typing 'exit' repeats the message and brings me back to the `(initramfs)` prompt. Typing 'fsck' returns `fsck from util-linux 2.27.1` and returns me to the `(initramfs)` prompt.

How do I fix the installation?

Comment: `fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` should do it.

Comment: Am I correct to say 'y' 'yes' to fix all the problems it's encountering? Doing so, after perhaps three dozen fixes it says, "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: **** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****" and "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 753569/7266304 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 762102/29051904 blocks" and I'm back at the `(initramfs)` prompt. I will try the `exit` command now -- which brought me back to the main login screen as normal. Thank you!

Comment: Yes .. you have to answer yes to fix errors. Or do `fsck -y /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` to automatically answer Yes to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` from that prompt, press `y` to say yes each time to fix everything found wrong, and then execute `exit` from that same prompt to return to the normal login screen.

Comment: Is it okay to answer your own question, with input taken from others (mine) comment ?

Comment: If you post your answer as an answer, I would accept it. I posted this answer to later accept it merely to "close the thread" so to speak, i.e. so that people using this site on other pages would see that this question has been answered. I think it is okay, as long as no other answers have been posted. If you were to post the answer after this one, I would try to 'unaccept' this answer to accept yours, which I think is possible. Why did you post your answer as a comment rather than an answer, by the way?