# How do I ascertain whether my computer has dedicated graphics accelerator and onboard graphic memory?

Tags: graphics, hardware, ram, hardware-acceleration

How do I ascertain whether this device has a "dedicated graphic accelerator" and "64 MB of on-board graphic memory"?

> Slicer requires a minimum of 2 GB of RAM and a
>     dedicated
>     graphic  accelerator
>     with    64      MB    of
>     on-board graphic   memory.

-- [introductory tutorial](https://www.slicer.org/w/images/5/55/SlicerWelcome-tutorial_Slicer4.5.pdf)

`lshw` lists, among others,

```
*-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: b
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3
             physical id: 0
             slot: SODIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3
             physical id: 1
             slot: SODIMM2
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits

*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:32 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:8000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I don't know whether these things accelerate graphics, are dedicated, or are graphic memory. I'm not even sure if a controller is the same thing as a graphics card.

My conclusion so far is that a controller is part of the CPU, not a graphics card, and that I do *not* have a 'dedicated' graphic accelerator, that this is referring to a graphics card with its own processor separate from the CPU, and likewise that this graphics card should have 64 MB of its own memory. Hence my tentative conclusion is that this computer cannot run 3D Slicer as designed, and my tentative answer to this question is "use `sudo lshw` and check the 'display' section", but I hope to hear from you to learn more, if I am mistaken.

Comment: "a dedicated graphic accelerator with 64 MB of on-board graphic memory" is fairly useless as a guide to whether a particular machine will run the software. I'd recommend just trying it and seeing if it works or not.

Comment: I have encountered errors, and [it froze my computer once](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002047/how-do-i-fix-my-computer-via-busybox), but I'm not sure if I was simply misusing counterintuitive software. I had hoped I was 'being smart' by determining here that a CPU graphics controller -- ie integrated graphics on a laptop, rather than a graphics card in a desktop computer -- was insufficient to run this software. On one hand the software appears to work, but on the other hand I've gotten IO error, loading data is slow, and my computer froze trying to load a CT, so maybe it doesn't work.

Comment: If you get IO errors, that might be the disk failing. Try opening the Disks program, opening the hamburger menu (☰) in the upper right corner, and running an extended SMART test.

Comment: Power-On Hours and Power Cycle Count are type 'Old-Age', and the other four (used-reserved-blocks-chip, used-reserved-blocks-total, unused-reserved-blocks, runtime-bad-block-total) are type 'Pre-Fail', but my understanding was that 3D Slicer was giving an IO Error because RTPLAN DICOM files are not supported (i.e. weren't in the previous version, and so aren't in this latest version 4.8, either).